# Proof C(n,r) = C(n, n-r)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hello just want to see if my proof is right, and if not could someone please guide me because I am not clearly seeing the steps to this proof. I don't know if I correctly solve the proof in the second to last step. If I did any mistake it would be great if someone could point at it.
$$
C(n, n-r) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!(n-(n-r))!} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)! (r)!} = C(n,r) 
$$

Comment: I've edited it, the proof looks fine to me. Can you think of a "combinatorial" proof of this equality?

Comment: The second formula after $C(n,n-r)$ should be the first formula.  The third should be the second.  And, the first should be the third.

Comment: proof could be just that whenever you select $r$ from $n$ you are also selecting $n-r$ from $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Let c(n,r) be the set of r element subsets taken from some n element set and define c(n,n-r) similarly. The complement map (restricted) bijects these two sets and so they have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

$ C(n, k)$ denotes the number of ways to select $k$ out $n$ objects without regard for the order in which they are selected. To prove  $C(n,r) = C(n, n-r)$ one needs to observe that whenever $k$ items are selected, $n-k$ items are left over, (un)selected of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

How to show this?
Choosing $r$ sets out of n possibilities is the same as selecting $n-r$ sets not to choose.